# Measure theory qualifying exam question

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

While studying old real analysis qualifying exams, I've gotten stuck trying to solve the following problem. Any hints would be appreciated.

If $E$ is a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb R$, show that
$$
  \lim_{t \to 0} \mu( E \cap (E+t) ) = \mu(E).
$$
Here $\mu$ denotes Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Certainly the limit is at most $\mu(E)$. Let $(a_1,b_1),\ldots,(a_n,b_n)$ be intervals with union $I$ such that $\mu(E\Delta I)<\epsilon$ where $\Delta$ denotes symmetric difference. Then
$$\begin{align}
\mu(E\cap (E+t)) &\ge \mu(I\cap (I+t))-\mu(I\setminus E)-\mu((I+t)\setminus (E+t))\\
&>\sum_{i=1}^n (b_i-a_i-t) -2\epsilon\\
&= \mu(I)-nt-2\epsilon>\mu(E)-nt-3\epsilon
\end{align}$$
and letting $\epsilon,t\to 0$ gives the desired result.

Comment: Should the last term on the first line be $\mu((I+t)\setminus(E+t))$?

Comment: @Dane Yes, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If $\mu E < \infty$, apply dominated convergence to
$$
    \int \chi_{E}(x)\chi_{E}(x-t)d\mu(x) = \mu (E\cap(E+t)).
$$

Comment: But now we have to show that $\chi_E(x-t) \to \chi_E(x)$ for almost every $x$.  That's not so easy to do from scratch.

Comment: Outer measure is from scratch, and you can show that $\phi(x-t)$ converges pointwise a.e. to $\phi(x)$ as $t\rightarrow 0$ if $\phi$ is a finite sum of characteristic functions of intervals, even if the intervals overlap. So, it's not too difficult with a standard 3-epsilon type of argument.